# Code works in JSFiddle but not in Web Browser or Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, show-hide

This code works in JSFiddle fine however when I put in in a dreamweaver document or try it in a browser the div never shows. The aim is to get the div 'sreturned' to show when the user selects value '1' from the drop down. I have the code in two seperate files and link them. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh%20HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thesurebettor/Untitled-2.js"></script>
 <select id = "typeoption"> 
 <option value="0">Qualifying Bet</option>
 <option value="1">Free Bet</option>
 <option value="2">Risk Free Bet</option>
 </select>
 <div style='display:none;' id='sreturned'> Stake Returned
 </div>
</body>
```

Here is the script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#typeoption').on('change', function() {
            if ( this.value == '1')
          {
            $("#sreturned").show();
          }
          else
          {
             $("#sreturned").hide();
           }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Read the error messages. I can see two likely (but completely unreleased) contenders.

Comment: It seems you're using jquery without including it.

Comment: Gargh. "unrelated" not "unreleased" in my previous comment.

Comment: @JordiNebot — There is nothing wrong with the position of the script element in the question. (Also: W3Schools, ick)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT: JSFiddle include jquery in all pages**

Do you have add jquery script ? Try this file :

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh%20HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thesurebettor/Untitled-2.js"></script>
 <select id = "typeoption">
 <option value="0">Qualifying Bet</option>
 <option value="1">Free Bet</option>
 <option value="2">Risk Free Bet</option>
 </select>
 <div style='display:none;' id='sreturned'> Stake Returned
 </div>
</body>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#typeoption').on('change', function() {
         if ( this.value == '1')
       {
         $("#sreturned").show();
       }
       else
       {
          $("#sreturned").hide();
        }
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works when I add it all into an HTML file however i could not get it to work when i add it to the seperate js file. How can I include the script src code in the external js file?

Comment: For add jquery, you need to add in your html this line : "<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
" and before your call script.js

Comment: Thanks for validate my answer ^^

Comment: awesome, its working now.. how would i go about adding more divs to the show/hide lines of code after the "#sreturned" ?

Comment: My english is so bad... If you want mask more element in same function, you can change selector jquery : "$("#sreturned, #sreturned2, .sreturned1").show();". It's what you want?